# Mysql sum not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to add up some records from a table, however, it isn't working properly, i.e. when i try var_dump to see what the value is showing i just get `string(0) ""`

Here is the code

```
 $current_wealth1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(estimated_wealth) as total_house_wealth FROM user_houses WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
var_dump($total_house_wealth);
$current_wealth = $ved_balance + $total_house_wealth;
```

In terms of output, i am just using conventional php print to output $current_wealth.

Any ideas, what could be the problem?

EDIT: Here is my current code, getting a syntax error on the second line

```
 $current_wealth1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(estimated_wealth) as total_house_wealth FROM user_houses WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
$total_house_wealth = mysql_fetch_array($current_wealth1)[0];
$current_wealth = $ved_balance + $total_house_wealth;
```

Comment: the function `mysql_query` doesn't work like that. just read the manual please, and take the RED HINTS about pdo/msqli to heart: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try splitting the fetch array to 2 lines to remove your syntax error?

```
$current_wealth1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(estimated_wealth) as total_house_wealth FROM user_houses WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
$total_house_wealth = mysql_fetch_array($current_wealth1);
$total_house_wealth = $total_house_wealth[0];
$current_wealth = $ved_balance + $total_house_wealth;
```

also, in your table structure, is user id a character string, or integer? if its an integer, then the `userid='$user_id'` in the WHERE clause shouldn't be single quoted (e.g. `userid=$user_id` *although you may want to sanitize the user_id var first*)

Answer (score 2):

You need of course to do

```
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($current_wealth1));
```

Also most likely you get a syntax error becuase you don't have php 5.4. You can't do `...)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

`$total_house_wealth` isn't declare nor set with any value, so what you are seeing is expected behaviour.  What you actually want is a different thing

```
$total_house_wealth = mysql_fetch_array($current_wealth1)[0];
```

Comment: thanks for the help, this is my first time doing mysql sum, so i didn't really think about fetching the array, although when i tried it, it said i got a syntax error on line 61, which is the line i put you code on. Any ideas?

Comment: Put it immediately before `var_dump($total_house_wealth);` in your original example.  Obviously, I can't see your line numbers.

Comment: ok i removed the var dump as i don't need it anymore, but now i get the error `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arken\profile1.php on line 61` I added my current code in my original post

Comment: I didn't see the far right bit of you SQL statement.  You have two problems with `WHERE user_id='$user_id'`.  The first is syntactic, it needs to be WHERE user_id='{$user_id}' in order to reference the PHP variable `$user_id`.  The second is SQL injection.  You need to `mysql_real_escape_string` it first: `WHERE user_id = '{mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)}'

Comment: okay but if i keep the [0] at the end of the fetch_array, then i still get a syntax error on that line, if i remove it, i get an error in the html.

Comment: It should work... you could try `["total_house_wealth"]`.  Try reading through the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).